# Exposing domain logic in webapi

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

So in REST I have a product resource...

```
http://api/product
```

Question is what if I've got some domain logic? In an Object Oriented world, I might have

```
public class product
{
    int id;

    public product(){}

    public int Calc(int first, int second)
    {
        return first + second;
    }
}
```

How do I represent this business logic? I assume I can do...

```
    public int GetCalc(int id, int first, int second)
    {
        localProduct = products[id];
        return localProduct(first + second);
    }
```

Hence the URL of the service would become

```
http://api/product/Calc?id=1&first=1&second=2
```

OR (alternatively)

```
http://api/product/1/Calc?first=1&second=2
```

This returns the correct result.... I'm just wondering if this is how I should represent business business logic? Or should I be doing this a different way or trying to avoid it altogether? I'd welcome any ideas on how to improve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably depends much on the system you build. Take time to think how this would evolve over time, as this is quite hard to refactor. The general direction you heading looks good.

This API call

```
http://api/product/Calc?id=1&first=1&second=2
```

looks right to me. So you have a `Product` controller that has a method `Calc` and takes in parameters `id`, `first` and `second`.

I am not too sure how to deal with this API

```
http://api/product/1/Calc?first=1&second=2
```

To me it reads a `Product` has many `ids`, each of `id` can call a method `Calc` with parameters `first` and `second`. Maybe in your business domain it make sense, I just fail to see it.

Comment: yeah.... I do wonder if it should actually be...

    _http://api/product?id=1/Calc?first=1&second=2

Answer (score 0):

Well, in theory REST shouldn't deal with logic but only with state (REST = representational state transfer).

Of course, I can see your point, what do I do if I need the calculated value?

In my opinion you should try to avoid it altogether.

If that's not possible I would just expose a ViewModel which represents the state of your object and keep the model with the logic hidden from the outside world. This assures you that you do explicit conversion and it also explicitly states that you are sending the **state** of an object and not the object itself.

But it basically depends on the situation and there's no real hard rule. I'd say go with whatever makes the most sense for now. If you ever find it becoming awkward, refactor it to a better solution.